# Win32 C/C++ Load Image from memory buffer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap

I want to load an image (.bmp) file on a Win32 application, but I do not want to use the standard LoadBitmap/LoadImage from Windows API: I want it to load from a buffer that is already in memory. I can easily load a bitmap directly from a file and print it on the screen, but this issue is making me stuck.

What I'm looking for is a function that works like this:

```
HBITMAP LoadBitmapFromBuffer(char* buffer, int width, int height);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, I found my solution! Here's the initializing code:

```
std::ifstream is;
is.open("Image.bmp", std::ios::binary);
is.seekg (0, std::ios::end);
length = is.tellg();
is.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
pBuffer = new char [length];
is.read (pBuffer,length);
is.close();

tagBITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = *(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER*)pBuffer;
tagBITMAPINFOHEADER bih = *(tagBITMAPINFOHEADER*)(pBuffer+sizeof(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER));
RGBQUAD             rgb = *(RGBQUAD*)(pBuffer+sizeof(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(tagBITMAPINFOHEADER));

BITMAPINFO bi;
bi.bmiColors[0] = rgb;
bi.bmiHeader = bih;

char* pPixels = (pBuffer+bfh.bfOffBits);

char* ppvBits;

hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**) &ppvBits, NULL, 0);
SetDIBits(NULL, hBitmap, 0, bih.biHeight, pPixels, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &cBitmap);
```

Comment: hello i am java developer but in my application i also need to load image from c++ and i don't know how to do it.
i am researching in internet for so long but still cant get it.
so will u please provide your whole code i required it badly. please

Answer (score 9):

Try [`CreateBitmap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
HBITMAP LoadBitmapFromBuffer(char *buffer, int width, int height)
{
    return CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 24, buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`CreateDIBSection` can be a little complicated to use, but one of the things it can do is create a device-independent bitmap and give you a pointer to the buffer for the bitmap bits. Granted, you already have a buffer full of bitmap bits, but at least you could copy the data.

Speculating a bit: `CreateDIBSection` can also create bitmaps from file objects, and there's probably a way to get Windows to give you a file object representing a chunk of memory, which might trick `CreateDIBSection` into giving you a bitmap built directly from your buffer.

Comment: CreateDIBSection is the correct API to use. The memory it uses has to be a particular kind of kernel memory (as the graphics device driver needs to access it) - which can be satisfied by a file section (being a kernel structure itself) or by letting CreateDIBSection allocate the memory.

Answer (score 1):

<s>No, but you can create a new bitmap the size of the current one in memory, and write your memory structure onto it.</s>

You're looking for the [CreateBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485(v=VS.85).aspx) function. Set lpvBits to your data.