# C++ HBITMAP from binary data

Tags: c++, bitmap, load, buffer

I'm using Winapi and I'm stuck. Normally to load image into SS_BITMAP on Dialog I'm using

```
HBITMAP hImage = ( HBITMAP ) LoadImage( hInstance, L"D:\\foo.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE );
HWND hFrame = GetDlgItem( hWnd, IDC_IMAGE );
SendMessage(hFrame, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hImage);
```

but now I have different task. I need to put there image from buffer which contains binary data of image. I've used some code but I know its wrong `SetBitmapBits( hImage, sizeof(image),image);`. `image` is char array with data.

Comment: What il your image format ? BMP ?

Comment: JPEG converted to BMP by GDI+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can use

- [`CreateDIBSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a bitmap memory structure
- [`SetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to fill it with your pixel data

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901465/591064) looks good to me.