# Legacy C++ code not displaying bitmap under Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, mfc

I have to get some legacy (XP) MFC code running under Windows 10. It runs fine under Windows 7. I haven't tried any other versions.

The idea is that there is a buffer in memory that contains the image pixel values in RGB.
Then to display the image to the screen it is transformed into a bitmap and then copied to the DC.

This is the function that does the display of the object to the screen.
It seems to work, but then nothing gets shown on the screen except a white box.

(The comments were already there! someone else must have had some fun with this as well!)

```
WORD* CFBuffer24::getBitmap(int nBitsPerPixel)
{
    // check operation is valid
    ASSERT(m_pFB[RED] && m_pFB[GREEN] && m_pFB[BLUE]);

    if (nBitsPerPixel == 24)
    {
        if(NULL == m_pbm24)
            m_pbm24 = new UCHAR[((m_fbSize.cx*3+3) & ~3)*m_fbSize.cy];
        ASSERT(m_pbm24);
        UCHAR* rptr = m_pFB[RED]->getPointer(0,0);
        UCHAR* gptr = m_pFB[GREEN]->getPointer(0,0);
        UCHAR* bptr = m_pFB[BLUE]->getPointer(0,0);
        UCHAR* sptr = m_pbm24;
        if (m_dGamma == 1.0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_fbSize.cx*m_fbSize.cy; i++, rptr++, gptr++, bptr++)
            {
                // Assumes 24bit display ie. B R G format
                *sptr++ = *bptr; 
                *sptr++ = *gptr; 
                *sptr++ = *rptr;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UCHAR* wLUT = new UCHAR[256];
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                int val = (int) (255.0 * pow((double) i / 255.0,1.0/m_dGamma) + 0.5);
                if (val > 255)
                    val = 255;
                wLUT[i] = UCHAR(val);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < m_fbSize.cx*m_fbSize.cy; i++, rptr++, gptr++, bptr++)
            {
                // Assumes 16bit display ie. 5R:6G:5B format
                *sptr++ = wLUT[*bptr]; 
                *sptr++ = wLUT[*gptr]; 
                *sptr++ = wLUT[*rptr];
            }
            delete [] wLUT;
        }
        return((WORD*)m_pbm24);
    }
    // 
    if (nBitsPerPixel == 16)
    {
        if(NULL == m_pbm16)
            m_pbm16= new WORD[((m_fbSize.cx*2+3) & ~3)*m_fbSize.cy];
        ASSERT(NULL != m_pbm16);

        UCHAR* rptr = m_pFB[RED]->getPointer(0,0);
        UCHAR* gptr = m_pFB[GREEN]->getPointer(0,0);
        UCHAR* bptr = m_pFB[BLUE]->getPointer(0,0);
        WORD* sptr = m_pbm16;
        if (m_dGamma == 1.0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_fbSize.cx*m_fbSize.cy; i++, rptr++, gptr++, bptr++)
            {
                // Assumes 16bit display ie. 5R:6G:5B format
                *sptr++ = (WORD) ((((WORD)*bptr>>3)&0x001F) | 
                        (((WORD)*gptr<<3)&0x07E0) | 
                        (((WORD)*rptr<<8)&0xF800));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WORD* wLUT = new WORD[256];
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                wLUT[i] = (WORD) (255.0 * pow((double) i / 255.0,1.0/m_dGamma) + 0.5);
                if (wLUT[i] > 255)
                    wLUT[i] = 255;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < m_fbSize.cx*m_fbSize.cy; i++, rptr++, gptr++, bptr++)
            {
                // Assumes 16bit display ie. 5R:6G:5B format
                *sptr++ = (WORD) (((wLUT[*bptr]>>3)&0x001F) | 
                        ((wLUT[*gptr]<<3)&0x07E0) | 
                        ((wLUT[*rptr]<<8)&0xF800));
            }
            delete [] wLUT;
        }
        return(m_pbm16);
    }
    // Bits per pixel must be wrong
    return 0;
}

bool CImDisplay::CheckDisplaySize(CSize Imsize)
{
    if (Imsize != m_Imsize)     // resize the buffer
    {
        m_Imsize = Imsize;
        // check the display capabilities
        CDC* pDC;
        pDC = m_pWnd->GetDC();
        //Get the display capabilities
        m_nBitPlanes = pDC->GetDeviceCaps( PLANES );    //Usually 1
        m_nBitsPerPixel = pDC->GetDeviceCaps( BITSPIXEL );//Usually number of colours
        m_pWnd->ReleaseDC(pDC);
        if( m_nBitsPerPixel != 16 && m_nBitsPerPixel != 24 )
        {
            ::MessageBox(::GetActiveWindow(),"Video mode is not compatable with\noutput resolution. Change Screen/Settings to 16 or 24 bits.","Unable to Display image", MB_ICONSTOP);
            return false;
        }
        if (m_pBuf != 0)
            delete [] m_pBuf;
        m_pBuf = new UCHAR[m_Imsize.cx * m_Imsize.cy * m_nBitsPerPixel / 8];
        if( !m_Map.CreateBitmap( m_Imsize.cx, m_Imsize.cy, m_nBitPlanes, m_nBitsPerPixel, m_pBuf ) )
            ::MessageBox(::GetActiveWindow(),"Can not create bitmap","Unable to Display image", MB_ICONSTOP);
    }
    return true;
}

void CImDisplay::Display(CFBuffer24* Image, CRect subRect)
{
    CheckWindowPointer();
    // Build the bastard bitmap
    CSize imsize = Image->getBufferSize();
    CheckDisplaySize(imsize);

    // Write the Data to the Bit map
    // Copies the image from our 24bit buffer into a bitmap and returns the pointer to the bitmap
    DWORD dRet = m_Map.SetBitmapBits(imsize.cx*imsize.cy*m_nBitsPerPixel/8, Image->getBitmap(m_nBitsPerPixel) );
    //Draw the bastard thing
    CDC* pDC;
    pDC = m_pWnd->GetDC();
    CDC MemDC;
    MemDC.CreateCompatibleDC( pDC );
    CBitmap *pOldBitmap  = MemDC.SelectObject( &m_Map );
    pDC->SetStretchBltMode(COLORONCOLOR);   // this gets the colours looking correct
    pDC->StretchBlt(  m_Location.TopLeft().x, m_Location.TopLeft().y, 
                            m_Location.Width(), m_Location.Height(),
                            &MemDC, imSubRect.left, imSubRect.top, 
                            imSubRect.Width(), imSubRect.Height(), SRCCOPY  );
    MemDC.SelectObject( pOldBitmap );               //Release the object
    m_pWnd->ReleaseDC(pDC);
}
```

I run the program in compatibility 16bit colour on Windows 10. This is so it will actually run, and it runs fine otherwise.

I have been able to get something to display on Windows 10 when I have used CreateCompatibleBitmap() instead of CreateBitmap(), but the colours are all garbled. On Windows 7, they are fine. Perhaps this is a clue, but I can't work out what it means.

Comment: What happens if you turn off that 16-bit color more and just let it run native?

Comment: The software will not run without that set. It checks the properties of the window for the colour depth and then terminates if it isn't 16 or 24 bit colour. It does a lot of image processing on those buffers and I'd rather not change all that if I can help it.

Comment: I found this code: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886831/win32-c-c-load-image-from-memory-buffer) but it uses some kind of RGBQUAD object which I'm not sure if I can create. If there was some way then it would probably work

Comment: So why not fix it to let it run at the native color depth?

Comment: change the condition to `if( m_nBitsPerPixel != 16 && m_nBitsPerPixel != 24 && m_nBitsPerPixel != 32 )` The rest is still wrong. Somewhere in your code you may have `GetDIBits` or `GetBitmapBits` which relates to `CFBuffer24`, show that function.

Comment: I've added the code that contains the getBitmapBits. It is in theImage->getBitmap() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can miscalculate required space for bitmaps if the width is not multiple of 4. It should be `required_size = ( (width * bits_per_pixel / 8 + 3) & ~3 ) * height`.

If `CFBuffer24` handles stride (bytes per row) correctly, you can do stretching blit directly to device context:

```
void CImDisplay::Display(CFBuffer24* Image, CRect subRect)
{
    CheckWindowPointer();

    CDC* pDC = m_pWnd->GetDC();

    m_nBitPlanes = pDC->GetDeviceCaps( PLANES );    //Usually 1
    m_nBitsPerPixel = pDC->GetDeviceCaps( BITSPIXEL );
    if( m_nBitsPerPixel != 16 && m_nBitsPerPixel != 24 && m_nBitsPerPixel != 32 )
    {
        ::MessageBox(::GetActiveWindow(),"Video mode is not compatable with\noutput resolution. Change Screen/Settings to 16 or 24 bits.","Unable to Display image", MB_ICONSTOP);
        return;
    }

    if ( m_nBitsPerPixel == 32 )
        m_nBitsPerPixel = 24;

    m_Imsize = Image->getBufferSize();

    // Bitmap rows are aligned to multiplies of 4 bytes
    int stride = (m_Imsize.cx * m_nBitsPerPixel / 8 + 3) & ~3;

    BITMAPINFO  bi =
    {
        sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER ),
        stride,
        -m_Imsize.cy,    // If bitmap looks upside down remove minus
        1,
        m_nBitsPerPixel,
        BI_RGB,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    };

    pDC->SetStretchBltMode(COLORONCOLOR);

    ::StretchDIBits(
            pDC,
            m_Location.TopLeft().x,
            m_Location.TopLeft().y,
            m_Location.Width(),
            m_Location.Height(),
            // !!!! I don't know what imSubRect is. Is it related to subRect?
            imSubRect.left,
            imSubRect.top,
            imSubRect.Width(),
            imSubRect.Height(),
            Image->getBitmap(m_nBitsPerPixel),
            &bi,
            DIB_RGB_COLORS,
            SRCCOPY );

    m_pWnd->ReleaseDC(pDC);
}
```

Above code leaves conversion from 24 to 32 bits to the `StretchDIBits`. It should be OK performance wise. Alternatively you can implement 32 bit case in the `CFBuffer24`.

Comment: I placed this code into the function and the result was garbled colours. I have updated my question with the code that is responsible for creating the bitmap from the buffer. There must be something in there that isn't quite right as well.

Comment: The good news is that it was able to show the same output on Win10, so this is the right track I think!

Comment: Thanks! I have been able to get it working. The problem was that I needed to go through and take out all the 16/24 bit colour restrictions and then run in in 32bit colour. With your code it was able to display!